# PHP - imagestring overlapping query results

Tags: php

I wonder if someone might help me with this piece of code? It is being designed to pull data with a query, then place said data in to an image. However, I am having an issue whereby all the rows of the query are being printed out on top of each other, rather than on a new line each time! I'm sure it's something simple I've overlooked, but any help would be appreciated! Also sorry it's under construction and doesn't look tidy! So to be clear, I am looking for it to loop through all the rows, and display them in a vertical list, however, it is currently showing them all on top of each other without any line break!

```
<?php

$config = parse_ini_file('inc/config.ini'); 
$config1["image"] = "images/back.jpg"; // The default background image
// Try and connect to the database
$connection = mysqli_connect('127.0.0.1:3312',$config['username'],$config['password'],$config['dbname']);

// If connection was not successful, handle the error
if($connection === false) {
    // Handle error - notify administrator, log to a file, show an error screen, etc.
}

$result = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT Name,PvPKills,PvEKills,NPCKills,HeliKills,APCKills,Deaths,Suicides,Status,TimePlayed FROM playerranksdb ORDER BY PvPKills DESC, PvEKills DESC, NPCKills DESC, HeliKills DESC, APCKills DESC LIMIT 10")
or die(mysqli_error()); 

// Make the image
        header ('Content-type: image/png');
        if(!isset($_GET['style'])) {
        $im = imagecreatefromjpeg($config1["image"]); } else {
        $im = imagecreatefromjpeg("image".$_GET['style'].".jpg");
        }

    // Various colors
        $textcolor = imagecolorallocate($im, 255, 255, 255);
        $border = imagecolorallocate($im, 135, 191, 231);
        $hpcolor = imagecolorallocate($im, 209, 48, 48);
        $mpcolor = imagecolorallocate($im, 204, 0, 255);
        $encolor = imagecolorallocate($im, 209, 184, 48);
        $oncolor = imagecolorallocate($im, 64, 225, 32);
        $offcolor = imagecolorallocate($im, 255, 80, 80);
        $rd = imagecolorallocate($im, 241, 241, 241);
        $rdblue = imagecolorallocate($im, 0, 180, 255);

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){

    // Level and name
        imagestring($im, 3, 22, 28, "<Lv".$row['PvPKills']."> ".$row['Name'], $encolor);
    }       
    // Display image
        imagepng($im);
        imagedestroy($im);

mysqli_close($connection);

?>
```

Comment: I assume it's because you're using the same co-ordinates every time - (22, 28). You should increase the Y co-ordinate each time. How much, I don't know, but you could try with 16 pixels and adjust from there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To expand on my comment:

```
<?php
$y = 28;
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    // Level and name
    imagestring($im, 3, 22, $y, "<Lv".$row['PvPKills']."> ".$row['Name'], $encolor);
    $y += 16;
}
```

Comment: @Samo Glad it helped. Please be so kind as to accept the answer. =)